# What happened to the MacTex 2016 download link?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

Does anyone know what happened to the MacTex-2016 link? It hasn't worked for days.

The old link is [here](http://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html). I really need to download a decent version. My MacTex is not working and I need to write a report in rmarkdown and I keep getting the error `! LaTeX Error: File 'titling.sty' not found.` Getting desperate.

Comment: Can you use the torrent download? The link is just below the download link in the page you linked above.

Comment: thank you @thepule I didn't notice that.

Comment: I actually upgraded to MacTex-2016 yesterday and the regular download link (http://tug.org/cgi-bin/mactex-download/MacTeX.pkg) worked OK.

Comment: Not since yesterday afternoon (days may have been an exaggeration). thanks to @thepule's suggestions I am torrenting it now. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: I can confirm it's working currently.

Comment: Thank you all I used the torrent link on the tug website and got it working.